# Trying to add values to the next empty cell in Excel using Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm relatively new to python and have picked it up as a hobby. I've been trying to make a password manager but to save variables I need to access excel files and copy variable data into the next empty row in columns A and B.

I have currently tried this to no avail:

```
value3 = v3.get()
value2 = v2.get()

folderPath = "C:\Password Manager"
if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
    os.makedirs(folderPath)
filename = "Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx"
filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
print(filePath)
open(filePath, "w+")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
ws = wb.active
for i in range (ws.max_row):
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value == None:
        ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = value2
        ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value = value3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, have been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: I think the problem might be `ws.max_row`. e.g, if row1-row4 already has password in them, then `ws.max_row` = 4. and your `if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value == None:` will always evaluate to false.

Comment: What is this line for `open(filePath, "w+")` You are opening a file handler on an file to be opened by Openpyxl for some reason, which ends up corrupting your Excel file. FYI An XLSX file is made up of directories of xml files, zipped together. Therefore when Openpyxl opens the file it unzips it to access the xmls. The line `files. open(filePath, "w+")` will create a new empty file with your filename `Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx" therefore it is no longer an Excel file and Openpyxl will return the 'zipfile.BadZipFile' error.

Comment: thank you for explaining! ive found a way to use a simple txt file instead using slicing and what not but ill definitely use this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Openpyxl 'append' it will always add the values to the next unused row in your Spreadsheet.

E.g.
Run the code as many times you like and the value2 & value3 values will be appended to the end of the sheet each time.

```
import os
import openpyxl

folderPath = "C:\Password Manager"
filename = "Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx"

value3 = 'password1'
value2 = 'password2'

if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
    os.makedirs(folderPath)
filename = "Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx"
filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
print(filePath)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
ws = wb.active

### Append the values as a list
ws.append([value3, value2])

wb.save(filePath)
```

[image]

Openpyxl append requires the values to be in a list (or a dictionary). When using a list each element is inserted into the next column, so for `[value3, value2]` `value3` in inserted in column A the `value2` into column B and so on for all the elements in the list. And always on the next free row.

FYI ws.max_row and append use the 'max row' as the last row with any cell with any value that is not (Python) None. So if you have only filled column A to 5 rows but Column Z has filled 10 rows then the next unused row will be row 11 (ws.max_row will equal 10).

Comment: I think it would be better to change `wb.save(filename)` to `wb.save(filePath)` in your code.

Comment: Thanks, yes should have been 'filePath'

Comment: wow thanks, i might actually change to this now! thank you all for so much help!

Comment: I have just tried this and it has made my life so much easier!!! thank you guys so much, i hope that someday i can be as good as yous!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the openpyxl doc on worksheet.max_row:
[worksheet.max_row](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html)

[image: worksheet.max_row]

If you want to write value to empty row, you need to start from `rowIndex = ws.max_row + 1`. not looping from `0` to `ws.max_row`.

e.g below will work:

```
       ws.cell(row=ws.max_row + 1, column=1).value = value2
       ws.cell(row=ws.max_row + 1, column=2).value = value3
```

If you really need a for loop to check each row, you can just change `for i in range(ws.max_row)` to `for i in range(1, 1000)`:

```
import openpyxl
import os

value3 = v3.get()
value2 = v2.get()

folderPath = "C:\Password Manager"
# if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
#     os.makedirs(folderPath)
filename = "Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx"
filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
print(filePath)
# open(filePath, "w+")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
ws = wb.active

for i in range(1, 1000):
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value is None:
        ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = value2
        ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value = value3
        break

wb.save(filePath)
```

If you need to input a list of passwords into column A and column B alternatively, you can try below for loop:

```
import openpyxl
import os

passwords = ["password1", "password2", "passw@rd3", "password4", "passowrd5"]

folderPath = "C:\Password Manager"
filename = "Encrypted_Passwords.xlsx"
filePath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
print(filePath)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filePath)
ws = wb.active

rowIdx = ws.max_row + 1
for i in range(0, len(passwords), 2):
    ws.cell(row=rowIdx, column=1).value = passwords[i]
    if i >= len(passwords) - 1:
        break
    ws.cell(row=rowIdx, column=2).value = passwords[i+1]
    rowIdx += 1

wb.save(filePath)
```

Comment: so I tried both the for loop and the top 2 lines of code and kept getting this as an error, (zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file), not quite sure what it means as the excel file is not zipped and the folder is not in a permission required area (such as program files)

Comment: ok so ive done some fidling and have finally got the error to go away (dont ask me how as i dont have a clue) but now the passwords entered first would save and then any others after that would overwrite the 2nd row meaning i could only store 2 passwords. any ideas?

Comment: The `(zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file)` error must come from `open(filePath, "w+")`

Comment: I added another code block in my answer to handle a list of passwords.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, ill try this now (I just got home from school), ill let you know if it works

Comment: so ive tried using the list code and for some reason the issue still remains that the first password is save properly (in cells A1 and B1) but any password after that is written into cells A2 and B2 only even if there is already one save there. im not quite sure why it isnt moving onto cells A3 and B3 instead of overwritting existing passwords

Comment: Are you sure you have `rowIdx += 1` in your for loop? also, do you know how to [debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) python code?

Comment: no i dont really know to much debugging but i can on simple projects, this is my first major project with a couple of external libraries, ill make sure that rowIdx += 1 is in my for loop

Comment: I see. it is still better to install Pycharm Community Edition or Visual Studio Code to write python. not only they have great debugging tools, they also have this great intellisense that helps improve your code. e.g, they will automatically help you changing `recursive function` to a `while loop`, invert `if condition` to avoid `nested if` etc.